# Hide MediaController after overriding hide()

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

We are developing an Android app where it is crucial to prevent the `MediaController` of a `VideoView` visible. This was achieved by overriding `hide()`:

```
mediaController = new MediaController(getContext(), false){
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        //Do not hide MediaController
        if (videoView.getVisibility() == VISIBLE){
            return;
        }
        //Hide only if VideoView is not visible anymore
        super.hide();
    }
};
```

The `VideoView` is part of a Fragment, and if this Fragment is removed and the next Fragment appears, the `MediaController` remains visible but not accessible. We tried different solutions to make sure `super.hide()` is called when the `VideoView` is removed, but with no success. The one above does not work. We also changed the if statement to:

- `if (videoView.isShown())`
- `if (videoView.isActivated())`

We even tried to manually `setVisibility(View.GONE)` for the MediaController in the `onDetach()` of the Fragment.

How can we properly hide the MediaController as soon as the Fragment is detached?

Answer (score 0):

We finally found a solution for the problem.

Override `hide()`:

```
@Override
public void hide() {
    //Do not hide MediaController
    if (videoView.isShown()){
        return;
    }
    super.hide();
}
```

In the `onDetach()`, call `hide()` manually after `super.onDetach()`:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mediaController.hide();
}
```

The `MediaController` will now be permanently visible for the duration the `VideoView` is visible. As soon as the `VideoView` disappears, the `MediaController` will disappear as well.